# Remotipart with Rails 3.1 - forms always submitted as HTML instead of JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3.1 I'm submitting forms with attachments via paperclip and remotipart.

I want my forms to submit via ajax but they are submitting via html.

It was working right in 3.0 but seems to have broken in 3.1. Note that by broken I simply mean that the form always submits via HTML and not JS so I can't render JS which I was doing before. The form still submits and the attachment gets saved, but I can't render JS. And yes, I have :remote => true

Thanks

Comment: Are your Javascripts being included properly?

Comment: Well, I thought so, but maybe not. I have //= require jquery.remotipart in my application.js file but when I search the generated javascript for 'remotipart' it doesn't find anything.

Comment: Oh, actually I did find it in there, so yes, the JS is in there.

Comment: It turned out to be something very strange that I still can't narrow down. If I rename my js manifest file everything is ok again. But I can use that same file from another controller in the app without renaming it. Very strange, but anyway I'm able to work around this be renaming the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I restarted my Webrick server, and the request was processed as JS.

Answer (score 0):

Remotipart submits forms that have multipart attachments via a hidden iframe (html).  Remotipart then wraps the desired json response in a `<textarea>` wrapper.  That is why you are seeing the html respones.  You can then call parseJSON on the data.responseText so to get your json resonse object.